# Load Website via Dedicted IP in CentOS + Direct Admin

Tags: apache, centos, directadmin

I use Direct Admin and Apache in CentOS 6.5, When i browse Server IP a white page load that **Apache is functioning normally** .
How can change this that when i browse IP see my website.com?
I don't want use IP/~Username method.

Answer (score 0):

For this you will have to assign dedicated IP for your website, so that you can access your site directly using IP

Comment: Yes, i have 2 Dedicated IPs for website, but IP Address Load Apache is functioning normally Page.

Answer (score 0):

Check this folder:
/var/www/html

There's your index.html file containing "Apache is functioning normally".

Also you can create sub-folders here and access them via:
http://ip/subFolderName